# How can I make my layout adapt to the Material-UI toolbar height?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently building the layout component (Navbar, Footer and Content), it looks like this:

```js
// containers/Layout/index.jsx
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main className={classes.root}>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

These are the styles:

```js
// containers/Layout/styles.js
export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    minHeight: `calc(100vh - 64px - ${theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight}px)`,
  },
}));
```

Now I ran into a problem, the Material-UI `Toolbar` is responsive. My footer is `64px` high, but my appbar is of course dynamic.

```js
// component/Appbar/index.jsx
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar />
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

For reference, this is what the mixin looks like:

[image: Mixin]

I'm trying to get the current height of the `AppBar` so I can make my `calc` function responsive. I've tried using the mixin but that only returns the normal minimum height. Another options is to use media query's, but I'd rather not since the media query is already present on the toolbar mixin.

How would I get this minimum height to adapt properly to the screen size? My goal is to always fill 100% of the screen with the footer at the bottom, with the content to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the default mixins of toolbar [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5a983eadb806ba095de2a2754b208d470e3f55e7/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMixins.js#L4-L10):

```
toolbar: {
  minHeight: 56,
  [`${breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
    minHeight: 48,
  },
  [breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    minHeight: 64,
},
```

It sets the `minHeight` to different values in different screen size/orientation. Similarly, in your main content below the header you should set the `height` to something like this:

```
content: {
  height: `calc(100vh - 56px)`,
  [`${theme.breakpoints.up("xs")} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
    height: `calc(100vh - 48px)`
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    height: `calc(100vh - 64px)`
  }
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67331031/how-can-i-make-my-layout-adapt-to-the-material-ui-toolbar-height]

Comment: Thanks! So there isn't an option to use like ``calc(64px - ${some_calculated_height})`` to keep it all in one line?

Comment: @Thimma by `some_calculated_height`, do you mean you want to find a cleaner way to code, or do you want to use a static value `some_calculated_height`? If it's the former then the answer is no. Otherwise, you can always override the toolbar mixins with your value in `createMuiTheme`.

Comment: With the calculated height I mean like a variable which changes accordingly to the screen size using the mixin, so I don't have to do 3 copies of the same query, if that's not possible then that's cool too

Comment: @Thimma one way to mitigate this is to put a link to the default mixins value like in my codesandbox, so future maintainers can understand why there is duplicated code.